# Новая Академия Изящных Искусств

Tags: прописная-строчная

Нужно ли все начальные буквы в названии Новая Академия Изящных Искусств делать прописными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно. В "Справочнике по русскому языку" Д.Э. Розенталя 2003 года - ***Академия изящных искусств***. С прописной буквы написано только первое слово.

***Новая академия изящных искусств*** - наиболее вероятное написание. Ср.: *Новый гуманитарный университет Натальи Нестеровой.*